# ASP Web APIs: Get content type of POST request

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services

I need to parse a JSON or BSON object. My method at `ApiController` controller class is defined this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public object ReceiveObjectAction()
{
    JObject body;
    var contentType = GetContentType(Request);
    if (contentType == "application/json") {
        body = JObject.Parse(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    } else if (contentType == "application/bson") {
        using (var reader = new BsonReader(Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
        {
            body = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        }
    } else {
        // throw bad request.
    }

    // process body, etc.
}

    public string GetContentType(HttpRequestMessage request) {
        <your answer here>
    }
```

Question: How can I implement the `GetContentType(HttpRequestMessage request)` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the Content header:

```
public string GetContentType(HttpRequestMessage request) {
    return request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
}
```